# How BeanPropertyRowMapper works internally in spring?

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I know that `BeanPropertyRowmapper` use `setter` method when I fire `select` query but **Is it uses `getter` method** ?

I am facing below issue:

In `database` ,  defaultPriority is in `string` but I want to set `int` value in my `SMSAction` pojo class.

```
class SMSAction implements Serializable {

private int defaultPriority;

public int getDefaultPriority() {
    System.out.println("Inside getDefaultPriority()");
    return defaultPriority;
}

public void setDefaultPriority(String defaultPriority) {
    System.out.println("Inside setDefaultPriority(String defaultPriority)"+defaultPriority);

    if(defaultPriority.equalsIgnoreCase("L")){
        System.out.println("Condition");
        this.defaultPriority = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select SMSACTIONID,SMSACTIONCODE,ACTIONDESC,CASID,DEFAULTPRIORITY from tblsmsaction]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17059]; Fail to convert to internal representation; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
```

How to solve above problem when data type are different in database and my pojo?
When I have changed **`return type of getDefaultPriority()` to `String`** then its **working fine** but i can't understood that why `BeanPropertyRowMapper` use `getDefaultPrioriy()` and also my `log` printed inside `getDefaultPriority()` **doesn't displayed**.

Note : I don't want to make my custom row mapper or hibernate or JPA.
Please help me.

Comment: That basically has nothing to do with Spring but with the Java Bean specification, that states that the type of getter/setter has to match.

Comment: @M.Deinum Currently i have not made bean of SMSAction (its pojo class) so why required to match  getter/setter ?

Comment: Because that is how it is specified in the Java Bean Specification that it is a requirement to match the type of the getter/setter. It doesn't matter if it is a bean or not when setting properties the Java Bean Spec applies.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok but How to solve this type of problem in which data type are different between database and my pojo ?

Comment: Use a separate, differently named, setter for the `String` based value or use a factory to create your objects.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you are doing something (not very) wrong. You have *some rules* to `set` something in your template (read `class`). Setters/Getters should be pretty neat; the fact that you need to store an `int` but you are applying some rule(s) to figure it out that `int` value has nothing to do with the way you set/get that particular value in a bean.

Whenever you are getting the `String` value from the database, apply the rule and call the setter:

```
// [db layer] here you already got the real value(s) through a database call
SMSAction action = new SMSAction();

// priority is some arbitrary name I used to simulate the variable that holds the String coming from the database
if (priority.equalsIgnoreCase("L")) {
  action.setDefaultPriority(1);
}
// ...
```

Now, some people prefer that kind of *business rules* in another layer, but that's a different subject; and as you can see it's easy to transfer the value(s) from layer to layer in a DTO/wrapper object or something similar.

Good luck!